# Is it possible to define two "SelectSingleNodes" statements while searching for a specific XML entry?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to define two "SelectSingleNode" statements while narrowing down a search for a specific XML value?

My XML structure is as follows:

```
<beans>
  <bean id="MenuGet">
    <property name="name">
    <property name="MapOverride">
      <map>
          <entry key="node.infoblock" value="k4jk2jb54B$T45bt2j5ktb3B%$">
      </map>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>

<beans>
  <bean id="SystemGet">
    <property name="name">
    <property name="MapOverride">
      <map>
          <entry key="node.infoblock" value="b34t34bhj54b%B#Y$%Bn45ht5h">
      </map>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

The statement I'm using to call the value I'm trying to pull from the first "beans" tag is below but I'm not sure if it's right or would work:

> $statement=$XMLFile.beans.bean.SelectSingleNode("id[contains(@key="Menu")]").property[1].map.SelectSingleNode("entry[@key='node.infoblock']").value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two entries with key "node.infoblock" in that file. If you want one entry per bean then you shouldn't use SelectSingleNode. It makes more sense to get them by using SelectNodes.

Second, the Xml file you posted cannot be parsed because it has format issues (there is no root node and many unclosed tags). It should look like this:

```
<beans>
  <bean id="MenuGet">
    <property name="name" />
    <property name="MapOverride">
      <map>
          <entry key="node.infoblock" value="k4jk2jb54B$T45bt2j5ktb3B%$" />
      </map>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="SystemGet">
    <property name="name" />
    <property name="MapOverride">
      <map>
          <entry key="node.infoblock" value="b34t34bhj54b%B#Y$%Bn45ht5h" />
      </map>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

If you save that file, entries can be retrieved running this code:

```
$xmlFilePath = "c:\temp\file.xml"
$doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.load($xmlFilePath)
$entries = $doc.SelectNodes("//entry[@key='node.infoblock'][1]")
foreach($entry in $entries)
{
    Write-Host $entry.value
}
```

It prints:

> k4jk2jb54B$T45bt2j5ktb3B%$
>
> b34t34bhj54b%B#Y$%Bn45ht5h

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't think to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

**A *single* XPath query and therefore a single `.SelectSingleNode()` call can do what you want**:

```
$query = '/*/beans/bean[contains(@id,"Menu")]/property/map/entry[@key="node.infoblock"]'
$XMLFile.SelectSingleNode($query).value
```

The above yields `k4jk2jb54B$T45bt2j5ktb3B%$`

<sup>Note:

- To match *multiple* nodes, simply use `.SelectNodes()` in lieu of `.SelectSingleNode()`; see the next section for an alternative using the `Select-Xml` cmdlet.

- The command assumes that your XML input is *well-formed*, which it currently isn't (missing root element, some missing closing tags); because the root element name isn't known, the query starts with `/*/`.</sup>

---

#### Alternative: using the `Select-Xml` cmdlet

[`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) essentially wraps the .NET `.SelectNodes()` method and adds the ability to process *multiple* inputs as well as the ability to target XML *files* by path directly:

```
$query = '/*/beans/bean[contains(@id,"Menu")]/property/map/entry[@key="node.infoblock"]'
(Select-Xml -LiteralPath file.xml -XPath $query).Node.value
```

Note the need to access the intermediate `.Node` property, because `Select-Xml` wraps the results in `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlInfo]` instances.

---

As for **what you tried:**

If you're calling `.SelectSingleNode()` (i.e., if you're using XPath) anyway, it is **better to locate the target node by XPath query *only*** - by calling `.SelectSingleNode()` directly on your *document* object, `$XMLFile` - and to limit use of PowerShell's dot notation to the *result* of that call - by accessing the `.value` attribute as a property.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49387055/45375) of mine for a **comparison of dot notation and `Select-Xml` use**.

Comment: Are there any good resources out there to learn how Powershell interfaces with XML or JSON files? Seems like there aren't that many that cover it.

Comment: @murkywaters: Re XML: please see my update, which hopefully gets you started; re JSON: JSON support is pretty straightforwards in PowerShell; so reading the `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` help topics may be all you need.