# Extract text between tags using PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have an XML file that includes many instances of a particular tag/element.  I am trying to capture each of these and then dump them into a new file.

I have the following script which does work, in that it takes the first occurrence of the text I am after and displays it to the console.

I am trying to incorporate foreach-object to retrieve all occurrences of ...allContent... but am failing to ge it added correctly.

Here is my working script that displays the output I am after for the first occurrence only.

```
$firstString = "<RunListItems>"
$secondString = "</RunListItems>"

#Get content from file
$file = Get-Content "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\ps\order.xml"

#Regex pattern to compare two strings
$pattern = "$firstString(.*?)$secondString"

#Perform the opperation
$result = [regex]::Match($file,$pattern).Groups[1].Value

#Return result
return $result
```

Comment: `$file = Get-Content "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\ps\order.xml" -Raw` and then `$pattern = "(?s)(?<=$firstString).*?(?=$secondString)"`, and then `[regex]::Matches($file,$pattern)` to get all occurrences. But it is not a good idea, you need to use the XML parser to handle XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing XML text with regular expressions is [brittle and therefore ill-advised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/45375).

PowerShell provides easy access to proper XML parsers, and the in case at hand you can use the [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) cmdlet:

```
Select-Xml //RunListItems C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\ps\order.xml |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Node.InnerText }
```

- `//RunListItems` is an XPath query that selects all elements whose tag name is `RunListItems` throughout the document, irrespective of their position in the hierarchy (`//`)
- The `.Node` property of the output objects (of type [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.selectxmlinfo)) contains the matching element, and its `.InnerText` property returns its text content.

**Note**: If your XML document uses *namespaces*, you must pass a hashtable with prefix-to-URI mappings to `Select-Xml`'s `-Namespace` parameter, and use these prefixes in the XPath query (`-XPath`) when referring to elements - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49387055/45375) for more information.

To save the output strings to a file, separated with newlines, simply append something like
`| Set-Content out.txt`; use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)'s  `-Encoding` parameter to control the encoding, if needed.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] In *Windows PowerShell* (versions up to 5.1), `Set-Content` defaults to the active ANSI code page. In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, the consistent default across all cmdlets is BOM-less UTF-8. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for more information.</sup>

Comment: Note that Select-Xml seems to struggle when namespaces are not properly defined and you have to use horrible local-name() syntax

Comment: @codeulike, no, you _can_ use namespaces (no need for `*[local-name()="foo"]` workarounds), but it requires more work - please see my update.